# Regex replace interpretation needed

Tags: c#, html, regex, xml

I have some code that is causing an error when the HTML is loade3d into  an XML doc. There are several Regex replace operations and not being a Regex expert I'm struggling to understand what they do.

The Regex is defined thus:

`private static Regex CleanseInlineTableBorder = new Regex("(?<TableTag><table[^>]*)border=\"1\"", rOpts);`

And is used like this:

```
fragContent = CleanseInlineTableBorder.Replace(fragContent, "${TableTag};");
```

However, it seems to be leaving trailing semi colons after removing the table border tag, e.g.

Name cannot begin with the ';' character, hexadecimal value 0x3B. Line 31, position 993.

HTML before: `<table tabIndex="-1" class="msoUcTable" style="BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; WIDTH: 167px" cellPadding="0" width="168" border="1">`

HTML AFTER: `<table tabIndex="-1" class="msoUcTable" style="BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; WIDTH: 167px" cellPadding="0" width="168" ;>`

I've already tried removing the semicolon from the regex:

```
fragContent = CleanseInlineTableBorder.Replace(fragContent, "${TableTag}");
```

but this didn't work.

Is there any way I can remove the semicolons by altering the regex somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fragContent = CleanseInlineTableBorder.Replace(fragContent, "${TableTag}");
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/16

`:` cannot appear if the code you have mentioned is same.If its still there you need to check source html .

Comment: I've already tried that and it didn't work (mentioned in post). The HTML doesn't have the ; in there as you can see from the HTML Before and HTML AFTER. It only appears after the Replace has happened.

Comment: Thanks for the link to regex101 - that was very useful. I can see the regex is removing the ; in that site. I can't understand how they appear in fragContent right after the replace though ...

Comment: Marking as correct as it is. The problem I am seeing is being introduced somewhere else in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution

```
fragContent = CleanseInlineTableBorder.Replace(fragContent, "${TableTag}");
```

should work assuming that fragContent initially contains what you called "HTML before". Are you sure that the value of fragContent actually contains the ; after applying the regex, or are you checking any other output than fragContent directly?

I will explain what your regex statement does:

```
(?<NAME>regex)
```

defines a named capturing group, meaning you look for something that matches the regex and assign a NAME to the result. You can use ${NAME} later on to access the match of your regex. Thus:

```
(?<TableTag><table[^>]*)
```

would match at most

```
<table tabIndex="-1" class="msoUcTable" style="BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; WIDTH: 167px" cellPadding="0" width="168" border="1"
```

since it starts with "< table" and collects any number of symbols until it runs into ">". However you put the expression

```
border=\"1\"
```

behind it, which matches "border="1"".

Thus the only match in your HTML Tag which satisfies your whole regex is

```
    <table tabIndex="-1" class="msoUcTable" style="BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; WIDTH: 167px" cellPadding="0" width="168" border="1"
```

where the part matching

```
(?<TableTag><table[^>]*)
```

(meaning the whole statement, except for border="1") is named "TableTag".

Finally by calling

```
CleanseInlineTableBorder.Replace(fragContent, "${TableTag};");
```

you take your initial HTML tag and replace the match of your regex (everything except for ">") with "TableTag" which is

```
    <table tabIndex="-1" class="msoUcTable" style="BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; WIDTH: 167px" cellPadding="0" width="168"
```

You see that after removing the ";" from your "Replace" call, there should be nothing left in your regex that can produce a ";".

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation - the dark arts of Regex :-) The html fragment is on of many and in the first run is output as HTML, there is a 2nd process to render as a pdf and this is where the problem is. The extra semicolon must be added somewhere in that process. Thanks again.